# URL authentication is not working on Icecast

Tags: audio-streaming, icecast

I configured URL authentication on Icecast.But, HTTP Basic authentication window pop up.

I think the window does not pop up if the authentication type is url.
How do i set?

```
<mount type="default">
</mount>

<mount type="normal">
  <mount-name>/ices</mount-name>
  <public>-1</public>
  <authentication type="url">    
    <option name="listener_add" value="http://localhost/listener-joined.php" />
    <option name="listener_remove" value="http://localhost/listener-left.php" />    
  </authentication>
</mount>
```

I want to authenticate in id which I set by oneself beforehand. I read by the document if I requested it in the URL such as the bottom when I could include it in data to post to listener-joined.php.

> /stream.ogg&session=xyz

So, I let the URL such as the bottom request it in a user and want to confirm whether id is registered with a database in a script.

> /ices&id=hogehoge

Comment: that setup looks reasonable. Have you checked if the URL for listener_add returns the necessary authorization header? Also the error.log might help you understand what's going on.

Comment: Also what do you mean by 'does not pop up'? Could you ammend your question to state what you are trying to achieve by configuring URL authentication. I suspect you might be misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [official documentation on URL based authentication](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/auth.html#url), specifically the *listener_add* section:
***Note:*** The mount here (unlike the start/end options) states the requested url including any query parameters, so for instance the requested URL can be /stream.ogg&session=xyz, but note that each option data is escaped before being passed via POST.

Your script (*listener-joined.php*) then has to interpret this data and if it is satisfied return the authorization HTTP header, which by default is: `icecast-auth-user: 1`

If your script does **not** return the header, e.g. because `id=foobar` is not allowed, then the Icecast server will refuse the listener connection with a HTTP status code of *401*. Most browsers and some players will then pop up an authentication dialogue.

There is a [ticket to make this configurable](https://trac.xiph.org/ticket/2192), e.g. to *403*, which would not pop up such a dialogue, or would allow redirects by 30x.